# How to parse a date as iso in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse a date in vb.net as below.

```
Dim EndDate As Date = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
If Date.TryParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, EndDate) Then
  EndDate = txtEndDate.Text
Else
  txtEndDate.Text = EndDate
End If
```

I cannot understand why my code above outputs `00:00:00`

**DESIRED RESULT**

If date input is not valid **`ISO`** date **`"yyyy-MM-dd"`** then

Set `txtEndDate.Text` and `EndDate` to date today as **`ISO`.

---

**EXAMPLE**

if I pass in `2016-15-10`

`EndDate` gets set to `#10/15/2016 12:00:00 AM#`

if I pass in `asfd`

`EndDate` gets set to `#1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#`

Comment: The last argument is supposed to be a date to store the result, you are passing a string. `Function TryParseExact(s As String, format As String, provider As System.IFormatProvider, style As System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles, ByRef result As Date) As Boolean`

Comment: Even when I set the variable as a date the output is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Comment: what is the value you are parsing?

Comment: See example above

Comment: Thats how it works.  If the string passed can be parsed, `EndDate` (as Date) will have the value.  If it cant (`TryParseExact` is a bool function) it will return false for you to do whatever in the `Else` -  you are setting it to `EndDate` anyway even when it fails

Comment: So how can I set my variable and input to a correct date if parse is false? and how can I set my variable to an ISO date if parse is true?

Comment: You are validating (parsing) a string.  Generally if it fails you want new input (no idea where these come from, a user?).  Note that a perfectly good date like `2016-10-5` will also fail with that format string because the day is not `dd` or '05`.  "yyyy-M-d" will parse 1 or 2 digits forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you not just do this:

```
Dim EndDate As String = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d")
If Not Date.TryParseExact(txtEndDate.Text, "yyyy-M-d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, EndDate) Then
  txtEndDate.Text = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-M-d")
End If
```

If it is successful then `EndDate` will be returned as expected however if not then just set to today as you were above.

Comment: Well if you want to be all logical about it. Sometimes the obvious is blinding. :)